# How to check if there was the execution of the servlet is Exception free

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I am fairly new to Java Servlets. I want to ensure that the execution on the server side code is exception free i.e I want to check if there was any exception thrown on the server code. How can I determine that using the response that I get?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, a Servlet executes server-side it's the server-side code that determines whether the client should be made aware of an `exception` or not. A client wouldn't come to know of it automatically unless the exception is not handled (within the servlet code) and no error pages were set for the web application (both of which aren't recommended).

Ideally, a client should never be made aware of the exact `exception`. Instead, the client should just receive a proper ***error message*** as to why the current request couldn't get processed successfully.

Error details should be shared on need to know basis. For example, if the input validation fails it makes sense to include the name of the field that was invalid in your error message. It isn't proper to show a `NumberFormatException` instead (say, because the client entered an age that was non-numeric).

***EDIT***:
There's no one single right approach here. There are various methods you can adopt based on how much descriptive your web application wants to be about the error to your client.

If you just require to let the client know that an error occurred with a brief error description you can use `sendError()` (which behind the scenes would automatically set the HTTP status header to an error code like *400 Bad Request* below)

```
if (request.getParameter("id") == null)
    response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "ID parameter missing");
```

Other approaches include configuring `<error-pages>` in your `web.xml` for different error codes or exceptions. The container would take care of automatically forwarding to the `.jsp` files configured below.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</error-code>
  <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The JSPs need to have their `isErrorPage` attribute set to `true` to receive an implicit `exception` object to get more information about the exception. For example, `exception.getMessage()` could be used (in some cases) to generate the error message to be shown to the user.

#### The client side

The client doesn't need to do anything special (like a getError()) to receive the error. The client would still be receiving HTML that gets rendered by the browser just like if the request had succeeded but since it didn't, the client would receive the error message formatted as HTML (can even `view > source` it).

The HTML sent depends on whether you used `sendError()` (which would send the standard error response from your web server like Tomcat) or your own configured `<error-page>` JSPs in which case you have complete control over your HTML error template.

Comment: So how should I notify to the client that something went wrong from the servlet? Should I set a header in the response that something went wrong and on the client side should I check this header? Is this the right approach?

Comment: Thanks ravi. One more question...how do I check the error in the client side? There is no getError()method ..is there anyother way? thanks

Comment: Yes, it's 400. You could use any one of the `HttpServletResponse.SC_*` codes that seem appropriate for your need. Check my "The client side" update as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the content from the servlet, there where not unhandled exceptions. If you want to get info of handled exceptions, log them in their `catch` clause.

Comment: How to I check if there were any exceptions of my client code?

Answer (score 0):

Use log4j to catch your exception (using try catch block) but if this is some kind of homework you are working then this might be one way you could check based on the http return code. you can use jquery  http://jquery.com/. Here is sample code for 404 error.
Also [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_http_status_codes.htm) page has all the http error code and what they mean.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
      var urlPath = "some_url";
      $.ajax(urlPath,
      {
         statusCode: {
         404: function() {
            alert('page not found');
         }
      }
   });   
});
</script>
```